# Navigation bar with page control on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iOS developing, I wanted to ask could someone help me how to make a page control(screen sliding) with navigation bar, I have tried a lot of things, I googled a lot but I couldn't find a solution.
I have a button when I click it will open a pagecontrol(rootview for screen sliding) with tableview which will change its data according to pages.
the problem is when I click that button I don't know how to get back to main page.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) is a good tutorial for learning how to create a page controller.

As far as your other problem of getting back to the main page, if you add a [bar button item](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to the root view controller's navigation bar, control-drag to your second view in your storyboard from that bar button item, a "Back" button will automatically appear in the upper left-hand corner of your second view controller.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it better to work with storyboard or with xib files?

Comment: In that case you may want to call `- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` from your button that brings you back to the root view controller. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW4). Storyboards are a bit more user-friendly if you ask me, especially if you're doing a lot of segueing.